# Drop multiple files onto executable C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, executable

I made an executable in which I want to drag any number of files onto. I want it to remove the first 15 characters of all of these files. It is renaming numerous files as hoped for but it throws an error afterward.

"Unhandeled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at RemoveTimeStampMultipleFiles.Program.Main(String[] args)"

When I drag 2 files is it then looking for a third?

Also is there a way to allow infinite files instead of having a max of 99?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace RenameVersion2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
                return; // return if no file was dragged onto exe


            for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
            {
                if (args[i].Length == 0)
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);

                string MyString = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[i]);
                String NewFileName = MyString.Remove(0, 15);


                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[i])
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + MyString
                   + Path.GetExtension(args[i]);

                string newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[i])
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + NewFileName
                   + Path.GetExtension(args[i]);


                File.Move(path, newPath);
            }


            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use a `foreach` loop, since you want to get all of the items in the collection.  There's also no reason at all to have `Environment.Exit` at the end of the program, the program is already ending.

Comment: for all files passed as args (provided you only have filenames as args), just use `foreach(var arg in args)`, and replace `args[i]` calls with `arg`.  As for the exception, did you try debugging? What happens when your filename is less than 15 characters long?

Comment: @Kolichikov has the right solution with `foreach`, but at the very least you should be using `for(i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)`. You already know about `args.Length` because you've used it above; why on Earth would you then hardcode in a high value of **99**? If `args.Length == 3`, then the second you test `args[i].Length == 0` and `i == 3` you've gone  past the end of `args`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application appears to be expecting exactly 99 arguments since your `i` loop goes from 0 to 98. Your error occurs because after processing however many arguments were passed it attempts to progress to the next which is not there. Try this instead:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace RenameVersion2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                if (arg.Length == 0)
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);

                string MyString = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arg);
                String NewFileName = MyString.Remove(0, 15);


                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(arg)
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + MyString
                   + Path.GetExtension(arg);

                string newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(arg)
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + NewFileName
                   + Path.GetExtension(arg);


                File.Move(path, newPath);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your `for-loop` so that it iterates over the available indices instead of going out of range.

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (args[i].Length == 0)
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);

                string MyString = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[i]);
                String NewFileName = MyString.Remove(0, 15);


                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[i])
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + MyString
                   + Path.GetExtension(args[i]);

                string newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[i])
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + NewFileName
                   + Path.GetExtension(args[i]);


                File.Move(path, newPath);
            }
```

The difference is here

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
```

vs

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
```